# how to interact with two beaglebone black connected to one computer

Tags: linux, git, ssh

Even after changing one of the BBB's IP, when i tried to connect, its configuration is reverting back to default, did somebody tried this, if so let me know with exact steps for the solution.
problem:
root@silvan-DL-H61MXP:~# ssh root@192.168.7.2

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@    WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!     @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!
Someone could be eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)!
It is also possible that a host key has just been changed.
The fingerprint for the RSA key sent by the remote host is
7d:0c:75:6f:f0:15:2f:13:39:f9:94:ba:88:30:61:e9.
Please contact your system administrator.
Add correct host key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts to get rid of this message.
Offending RSA key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:1
  remove with: ssh-keygen -f "/root/.ssh/known_hosts" -R 192.168.7.2
RSA host key for 192.168.7.2 has changed and you have requested strict checking.
Host key verification failed.
```

Comment: `remove with: ssh-keygen -f "/root/.ssh/known_hosts" -R 192.168.7.2`, it says. Have you tried it?

Comment: yes i have,still problem stays

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution for connecting with ssh to such development systems, which often loose their configuration is to disable host key checking and storage for them.

In your case this can be done by putting this into ~/.ssh/config:

```
Host 192.168.7.*
    UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
    StrictHostKeyChecking no
```

However, be careful not to disable host key checking and storage for normal systems as this would open them up for man-in-the-middle attacks.

Comment: there is no config file found,what to do ?

Comment: @virtplay Create it with the above contents.